# How to map Object with 4 properties to Object with 3 properties?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object

I have two Object

one is role:

```
Role {
    roleId: string;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    isModerator: string;
}

role = {
    roleId:"8e8be141-130d-4e5c-82d2-0a642d4b73e1",
    name:"HR",
    description:"HR of the Company",
    isModerator:"N"
}
```

and 2nd is roleDetails:

```
RoleDetails {
    name: string;
    description: string;
    isModerator: string;
}
```

I want to assign `roleDetails = role;`
so when I `console.log(roleDetails)`
I should get:

```
roleDetails = {
    name:"HR"
    description:"HR of the Company"
    isModerator:"N"
}
```

Comment: TypeScript is _structurally_ typed - anything that's a Role is also a RoleDetails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Omit<Type, Keys>](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) to declare type `RoleDetails` omitting keys

- in this case `roleId`

Code:

```
interface Role {
  roleId: string;
  name: string;
  description: string;
  isModerator: string;
}

type RoleDetails = Omit<Role, 'roleId'>;

const role: Role = {
  roleId: '8e8be141-130d-4e5c-82d2-0a642d4b73e1',
  name: 'HR',
  description: 'HR of the Company',
  isModerator: 'N',
};

const roleDetails: RoleDetails = {
  name: role.name,
  description: role.description,
  isModerator: role.isModerator,
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply assign each property individually (also note I've added `,` in your original object between each value):

```js
let role = {
  roleId: "8e8be141-130d-4e5c-82d2-0a642d4b73e1",
  name: "HR",
  description: "HR of the Company",
  isModerator: "N"
};

let roleDetails = {
  name: role.name,
  description: role.description,
  isModerator: role.isModerator
};

console.log(roleDetails);
```

You could also do this dynamically with an array of keys:

```js
let role = {
  roleId: "8e8be141-130d-4e5c-82d2-0a642d4b73e1",
  name: "HR",
  description: "HR of the Company",
  isModerator: "N"
};

let keys = ["name", "description", "isModerator"];

let roleDetails = Object.entries(role).reduce((a, [k, v]) => {
  if (keys.includes(k)) a[k] = v;
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(roleDetails);
```

And also with an array of keys to exclude:

```js
let role = {
  roleId: "8e8be141-130d-4e5c-82d2-0a642d4b73e1",
  name: "HR",
  description: "HR of the Company",
  isModerator: "N"
};

let keysToExclude = ["roleId"];

let roleDetails = Object.entries(role).reduce((a, [k, v]) => {
  if (!keysToExclude.includes(k)) a[k] = v;
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(roleDetails);
```